# Error:System.Text.Encoding' does not contain a definition for 'Default'

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am getting the following error:
'System.Text.Encoding' does not contain a definition for 'Default'
when I am trying to use Default method of Encoding through

```
var str2 = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(bytearray);
```

Through,MSDN I have learn there exist Default method in System.Text.Encoding, then why I am getting this error?
MSDN refrence for Default is here:[enter link description here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.default.aspx)

please help me out.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2010 express for Windows Phone.

Comment: Use `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8` instead.

Answer (score 7):

`Encoding.Default` refers to the system-default ANSI code-page in regular windows, inherited from the depths of time. Even on regular windows, it is ***not*** a good idea to use `Encoding.Default`. No such concept exists on windows phone, so : use the **correct** encoding; which *usually* means `.UTF8`.

Windows phone does not use the same .NET framework as windows, although they are very similar and much code will compile identically.

Comment: What about when I get a string that is encoded with "Default" ? I can't decode it with UTF8....

Comment: @CodeOrElse it isn't "encoded with Default" - that's not an encoding; it is encoded with a specific machine's operating system's default encoding at that time, which can be dependent on the machine, locale, and patch level. If I were you, I'd try to figure out what encoding that actually was, and decode it *specifically with that*, and stop using Default. Again: Default **is not an encoding** - it is basically a wild guess mixed with a roll of the dice.

Comment: Oh it's machine-dependant. Thanks, makes sense then!

Answer (score 3):

On the MSDN page you linked, if you expand the "Other versions" dropdown, you'll see that Silverlight (and therefore Windows Phone) isn't listed. The same way, if you look at the members of the Silverlight version of `Encoding`, you won't find `Default`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Text.Encoding_properties(v=vs.95).aspx

Use `Encoding.UTF8` instead:

```
var str2 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytearray);
```